# What is the correct ordering of Django middleware?

Tags: python, django

This page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/#middleware-ordering has/implies the following ordering (**Question #1:** Am I correct in assuming the list is in correct order?)

1. UpdateCacheMiddleware
2. GZipMiddlewaree
3. ConditionalGetMiddleware
4. SessionMiddleware
5. LocaleMiddleware
6. CommonMiddleware
7. CsrfViewMiddleware
8. AuthenticationMiddleware
9. MessageMiddleware
10. FetchFromCacheMiddleware
11. FlatpageFallbackMiddleware
12. RedirectFallbackMiddleware

while the graphic at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order seems to indicate that CommonMiddleware should be before SessionMiddleware:

[image]

In Django 1.5 `django-admin.py startproject` generates (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

while versions starting with 1.6 generate (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

**Question #2:** Should I change the order in my 1.5 projects so SessionMiddleware is before CommonMiddleware?

**Question #3:** How will requests be processed differently when switching the order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FYI, you may be interested in reading [Django 1.7 Middleware Ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/#middleware-ordering).
It explains the consequences of the middleware ordering, and I think it still applies on previous Django versions.

> Middleware ordering Here are some hints about the ordering of various
>   Django middleware classes:
>
> #### UpdateCacheMiddleware
>
> Before those that modify the Vary header (SessionMiddleware,
>   GZipMiddleware, LocaleMiddleware).
>
> #### GZipMiddleware
>
> Before any middleware that may change or use the response body.
>
> After UpdateCacheMiddleware: Modifies Vary header.
>
> #### ConditionalGetMiddleware
>
> Before CommonMiddleware: uses its Etag header when USE_ETAGS = True.
>
> #### SessionMiddleware
>
> After UpdateCacheMiddleware: Modifies Vary header.
>
> #### LocaleMiddleware
>
> One of the topmost, after SessionMiddleware (uses session data) and
>   CacheMiddleware (modifies Vary header).
>
> #### CommonMiddleware
>
> Before any middleware that may change the response (it calculates
>   ETags).
>
> After GZipMiddleware so it won’t calculate an ETag header on gzipped
>   contents.
>
> Close to the top: it redirects when APPEND_SLASH or PREPEND_WWW are
>   set to True.

#### Updates (as pointed by OP in comments)

The relevant change seems to be [Enabled the locale middleware by default](https://github.com/django/django/commit/eac747e848eaed65fd5f6f254f0a7559d856f88f).

In the comments from that commit:

> +.. versionchanged:: 1.6
>   + In previous versions, `` LocaleMiddleware` wasn't enabled by default.
>   +
>   +Because middleware order matters, you should follow these guidelines:
>   * Make sure it's one of the first middlewares installed.
>   * It should come after ``SessionMiddleware`, because`LocaleMiddleware`makes use of session data. And it should come
>   before`CommonMiddleware`because`CommonMiddleware`needs an
>   activated language in order to resolve the requested URL.
>   * If you use`CacheMiddleware`, put`LocaleMiddleware`` after it.

So, in fact the new changes in ordering is to resolve enabling LocaleMiddleWare by default. You shouldn't need to change these orders in previous `Django`'s versions because it's not enabled by default.

#### Update

`LocaleMiddleware` has been [removed from the project template](https://github.com/django/django/commit/23229061fcb836ecca2195cc75f91e331279a5d1)

Comment: That is indeed where my first link points to (although to the dev version, not the 1.7 version).  I'm still unclear about why CommonMiddleware now should go after SessionMiddleware though -- I thought the ETag calculations needed to include the session cookie... am I wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that `SessionMiddleWare` will modify the Vary header that might give better performance on `Django`'s caching, however I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @thebjorn, I have looked into the source, and seems that ordering change has something to do to fix a possible leak, well I'm still not 100% sure though, but hope this helps :)

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide the source difference, I'll try to find any real reference.

Comment: it is intended to fix "unnecessary session data", see this [Fixed #20936](https://github.com/django/django/commit/393c0e24223c701edeb8ce7dc9d0f852f0c081ad).

Comment: I think that is unrelated. The relevant change seems to be https://github.com/django/django/commit/eac747e848eaed65fd5f6f254f0a7559d856f88f although it doesn't mention Sessin/CommonMiddleware...

Comment: @thebjorn, well researched! Nice one, I will update the answer as you pointed without any personal comments.

Comment: I have included my findings from that commit and answered edited, too :)